# WebSocket with Spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm trying to permitAll the request made with websocket in spring security but everytime it goes to check if it has the jwt

this is my method in webSecurityconfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.debug( "configuration secutity called!");
        http.httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/favicon.ico","./favicon.ico","*/**.html",
                        ,"/active-users",
                        "/ws"
                        ,"*/ws"
                        ,"*/ws/**"
                        ,"/ws/**"
                        ,"/v3/api-docs/**"
                        , "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
```

and this is my websocketConfiguration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ActiveUsersWebSocketHandler activeUsersWebSocketHandler;

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler defaultSockJsTaskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(activeUsersWebSocketHandler, "/active-users")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                );
```

In debug, everytime i make a request with ws i always see it goes in my filter method: doFilterInternal, but shouldn't go there, any solution or am I missing any endpoint?